# Are there any existing setups for Listings to provide syntax highlighting for Antlr4 (.g4) grammar files in LaTeX?

Tags: listings, syntax-highlighting

I have been using the Listings package for C and Java highlighting and I also need to highlight my Antlr4 grammar code, which is of the .g4 format. Are there any existing setups for this, preferably in the Listings package, or otherwise?

Comment: Excuse me. But your question is related with LaTeX?

Comment: Great question, I was searching for this myself, but could not yet find a nice listingstyle

Comment: Sebastiano it is for latex environment the highlighting is needed. Ill edit the title for better explanation

Comment: Its just EBNF, but the files in antlr4 (.g4), have some additional syntax besides regular EBNF, so thats why I called it antlr4 grammar, though it's maybe not correct to call it a grammar. I was unsure what to call it? Its EBNF and then there are some additional elements added, like labels using #, for when antlr generates visitor methods. There are certain characters to escape. Non-terminals have to be small letters and terminals have to be all caps.